# After GRUB loads linux: No init found

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs

When I start Ubuntu from the grub, I get a strange message, and a medieval prompt as:

```
No init found

Busybox v1.15.3(ubuntu 1.1.15 3-ubuntu5) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of commands

(initramfs)_
```

I use a dualboot system, with Ubuntu Meerkat, and Windows 7.
Is there any chance of recovery? Thanks.

EDIT: The PC on a whim decide to boot itself up, and so I couldnt try the solution mentioned below. I will accept the answer anyway.

Comment: Is this a new Ubuntu installation, or one which you have been using for awhile?

Comment: Alright we need to see the output of bootscript first.Post the results of http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @karthick alright, here you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/546156/

Comment: @koanhead this is a aprx a 1 year old install, that I upgraded to 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot a ubuntu live cd,open a terminal and run the following

`sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda5`
`sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda8`

**Note:**
Running e2fsck will help you,if not we want to re-install grub.Return back if it din help you.

Comment: ill do that when I return home, but do u mind telling me what that does?

Comment: @kaustubh-p That could solve the problem which is not finding init.

Comment: can i do this with any ubuntu live cd? i have a ubuntu server cd.

Comment: Yes you can use any ubuntu live cd.

Comment: well, out of the blue the PC is working again. So ill accept the question anyway.