# 10.04 drops to '(initramfs)' prompt on boot

Tags: boot, boot-failure, initramfs

I'm not sure what to do to solve the problem, I received this error upon boot.

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/f60e3ce2-0237-45bb-bf07-581d0090cbc7 on /root
failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Comment: Try the solutions from these possible duplicate questions: **A**) [After GRUB loads linux: No init found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18101/after-grub-loads-linux-no-init-found), **B**) [PC doesn't boot and shows “No init found”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144037/pc-doesnt-boot-and-shows-no-init-found), **C**) [init not found try passing init=bootargs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32384/init-not-found-try-passing-init-bootargs), **D**) [No init start up error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16562/no-init-start-up-error).

Comment: Here is a good guide on system recovery: [boot failure - How to restore...][1]

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels